# Is it possible for a non-well ordered but linearly ordered set to have a proper $<$-inductive subset?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Say we have a set $S$, which is linearly ordered, but **not well ordered**. Let $B$ be a subset of $A$ such that $\forall t\in A$, $$\text{seg }t\subseteq B\implies t\in B$$

Here, $\text{seg }t=\{x\in A|x<t\}$.

Is it possible that $B\neq A$? In other words, is it possible that $B$ is a proper subset of $A$?

Motivation: My book says that if $B=A$, then $A$ is well-ordered. Hence, if $A$ is not well-ordered, it should be possible that $B\neq  A$. However, I cannot see how this would be possible, except if for every $t\in A$, $\text{seg }t\not\subseteq B$. Moreover, this is only possible if $A$ does not have a least element, as $\emptyset\subseteq B$, and $\emptyset$ is $\text{seg }t_0$, where $t_0$ is the least element of $A$. Hence, if $A$ has least element $t_0$, then $t_0\in B$,  and every subsequent  element in $A$ will fall into $B$.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the definition seg t?

Comment: @William- seg t={x|x<t}

Comment: @William- I have completely edited the question. Kindly check.

Comment: “every subsequent element in $A$ will fall into $B$” – doesn’t talking about “subsequent elements” presuppose a well-ordering (or at least something much stronger than a linear order)?

Comment: @k.stm- Talking of every subsequent element **after a particular element** presupposes only linear ordering.

Comment: @algebraically_speaking Okay, so by “subsequent” you just mean “greater” and not “the least greater”, right?

Comment: Also, something’s wrong: What do you mean by “if $A = B$, then $A$ is well-ordered”? Any linearly ordered set $A = (A,<)$ *trivially* satisfies $∀ t ∈ A\colon\; \operatorname{seg} t ⊂ A → t ∈ A$.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  Consider the $>$ relation on $\mathbb{N}$, and let $B$ be $\varnothing$.  Trivially for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have that $\mathrm{seg}_> (n) = \{ m \in \mathbb{N} : m > n \} \nsubseteq \varnothing$, and so the implication $\mathrm{seg}_> (n) \subseteq \varnothing \rightarrow n \in \varnothing$ is true.

But clearly $\varnothing \neq \mathbb{N}$.

---

This can be generalised.  Suppose that $\langle X , < \rangle$ is any linearly ordered set which is not well-ordered.  Since it is not well-ordered, there is a strictly decreasing sequence $\langle x_n \rangle_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $X$ (*i.e.*, $x_{n+1} < x_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$).  Then $$B = \{ x \in X : ( \forall n \in \mathbb{N} ) ( x < x_n ) \}$$ can be shown to be an "inductive" subset which is not all of $X$.  (It *may* happen that $B = \varnothing$, but this is not always going to be the case.)

Comment: Yes, but I had assumed $A$ to be non-well ordered. Also, a nonempty $<$-inductive subset I think would be more helpful.

Comment: @algebraically_speaking $(ℕ,>)$ is not well-ordered (as opposed to $(ℕ,<)$.

Comment: @k.stm- What is the difference? For any two $a,b\in (\Bbb{N},>)$, we have $a<b,a>b$ or $a=b$. Moreover, we can also find the least element of every $B\subseteq A$ by $\forall t\in B,t>t_0$ or $t=t_0$. Hence, $(\Bbb{N},>)$ too seems to be well ordered.

Comment: In $(ℕ,>)$, order-theoretically speaking, $1$ is a *maximal* element. And $\mathrm{seg} n = \{n+1, n+2, …\}$, and so $(ℕ,>)$ doesn’t have a least element as $n+1 > n$. You change the direction of ordering.

Comment: @algebraically_speaking: A linear order is a well-order iff every nonempty subset has a _least_ element (with respect to the order). Note that a _least_ element with respect to $>$ corresponds to a _greatest_ element with respect to $<$. Is there a greatest natural number?

Answer (score 0):

A non-trivial example: $B = [0..√2)∩ ℚ$ in $A = [0..∞) ∩ ℚ$ with the usual order. $B$ is closed in $A$ (in the order topology), so $∀ t ∈ A\colon\; \operatorname{seg} t ⊂ B → \overline{\operatorname{seg} t} ⊂ B$. This implies the condition required. Here, $A$ even has a least element.

The thing is, any set which does not contain any segments (or left-sided rays) in any linearly ordered set *trivially* satisfies the condition. So for example any bounded interval in $ℝ$ gives you such an example. Or any subset of $ℕ$ not containing $1$.

And this brings me to my question, as already stated in a comment: What do you mean by “if $B = A$, then $A$ is well-ordered”? Because, as I understand it, neither “if *only* $A$ has this property, then $A$ is well-ordered” nor “if $A$ (among maybe other subsets) has this property, then $A$ is well-ordered” is true.